# Given $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ find the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Tags: statistics

> $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
> 0&:& x<0, y<0\\ 
> xy^2&:& 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
> x&:& 0\leq x\leq 1, y\geq 1\\
> y^2&:& x\geq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
> 1&:& x>1, y>1
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Find the join density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Since I know $$P(a\leq X\leq b, c\leq Y\leq d)=\int_c^d\int_a^bf(x,y)dxdy$$

Does that mean I have:

$xy^2=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That means that for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$,
$$xy^2 = \int_0^y \int_0^x f(s,t)\, ds\, dt.$$
Moreover, for absolutely continuous distributions, the CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f(s,t)\,ds\,dt.
$$
So for almost all point, $$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}.$$
You can find mixed secon order partial derivative inside unit square and obtain  joint probability density function. You can then check whether it is PDF. To do it, check 
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy =1.
$$

Comment: So I have $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
0&:& x<0, y<0\\ 
2y&:& 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
0&:& 0\leq x\leq 1, y\geq 1\\
0&:& x\geq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
0&:& x>1, y>1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: And you are right.

Comment: I don't see how to check the integral though $\int_0^1\int_0^1 2y dydx$. I get that it's 1/3.

Comment: $\int_0^1 2y\,dy=y^2\mathop{\Big|}_0^1=1$, so...